# Is there a way to specify the file name in advance for the picture taken with the flutter camera plugin?

Tags: flutter, dart, camera, flutter-plugin

Hi I am using the [flutter camera plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/camera) and it works fine, the main issue I am having is that I can't find a way to tell the plugin the image file name when taking the picturee, in android using Kotlin this would be something like:

```
photoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(requireActivity(), "io.awesomedomain", photoFile) // build uri on the app storage space and specific file name -> photoFile.
captureImageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoUri) // define the pic name before picture is actually taken by the camera.
startActivityForResult(captureImageIntent, REQUEST_PHOTO) // start the camera
```

I am currently just renaming the picture file name after the picture XFile returns from the flutter camera plugin but this doesn't feel optimal so I am wondering if I am missing something. Is it possible to specify the file name in advance to the flutter camera plugin?

I am currently using the latest available version at the moment: `camera: ^0.7.0+2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, it looks like I had a misunderstanding of the Camera plugin, I noticed that the returned XFile places the picture in the cache directory and actually provides a method to save the picture to a more definitive storage `xfile.saveTo` so I did:

```
var appDir = appDocDirectory.parent.path; // get app directory    
file.saveTo('$appDir${Platform.pathSeparator}files${Platform.pathSeparator}${weightPicture.pictureFileName}');
```

So the picture is properly saved under $myAppDir/files/picName.jpg where the files is a directory I configured to have permission to write to and the picName is defined by the application as I wanted.